Modelling Conditional Probabilities with Continuous Givens
I'm currently struggling with this equation
$$ p(x; \theta) = P(Y = 1 | X = x) $$
where $p$ is our model for the conditional probability on the right. Surely this equation does not make sense if $X$ is a continuous random variable. Do we simply treat $X$ as discrete?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please explain why you think the equation does not make sense if  is a continuous random variable?

Is it fair to say your confusion arises because, if you express this probability rule according to the definition for discrete events (i.e. P(Y=y|X=x) = P(Y=y, X=x)/P(X=x)) then you get P(X=x) in the denominator which is 0?

@AdamO exactly.

The definition of $p(x;\theta)$ would require the rhs to involve $\theta$.

$p(x;\theta)$ is a bad choice of notation, in my opinion, consider it as a function, so more like $f(x;\theta)$.
For, $P(Y=1|X=x)$, try reading it with an example, say $X$ = age, $Y$ = having a child, thus $P(Y=1|X=x)$ = "Given you are $x$ years old, what's the probability of you having a child"
Now, given this interpretation, I think you can see how $X$ can be continuous

Age being the number of Planck time from your birth, so that you can consider it to be continuous, of if you prefer, use height instead

Age is discrete. Are you agreeing then that $X$ is treated as discrete?

@AdamO is it better now?

The answer to your question is no we do not treat $X$ as discrete.
A comment: judging from notation I guess this is from logistic regression which, from a statistics standpoint, is very intuitive but from a probability standpoint invokes a great leap of faith into measure theory. From a graduate level maths perspective, there is no reason to distinguish continuous and discrete probability distributions- this is why many UG textbooks (cough cough Hogg and Craig) awkwardly present separate "versions" of the same definitions and theorems for continuous and then discrete distributions.
The definition of conditional probability for discrete events is indeed:
$$P(Y=y|X=x) = \frac{P(Y=y, X=x)}{P(X=x)}$$
Analogously for continuous distributions:
$$f_{Y|X}(y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(y,x)}{f_X(x)}$$
(And continuous and discrete versions of Bayes' Rule can be derived).
Expressing a joint distribution of what is a continuous and discrete variable is challenging. The easiest way to gain an understandable version of this is to rely on the probability density as an infinitessimal. This is not a necessary condition, but if X has a smooth density, $$P(Y=y|X=x) = \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{P(Y=y, x \le X < x+\delta)}{P(x \le X < x+\delta)}$$
